How to repair a PC with the error "Boot Device not found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk. Hard disk (3F0)"
My Windows 10 machine is HP Envy core i7, 16 GB of RAM and is dualbooted with Ubuntu 24. The Ubuntu installation is on a separate physical drive (There are 2 physical 750 HDDs in the PC). I don't know exactly where the Windows bootloader and Ubuntu bootloader is installed (if I'm using the correct terms). But I'm using Grub to manage both boot loaders/installation.  A few days ago upon booting, it says that my fan isn't working well and that I would experience frequent shutdowns. However, due to incessant power cuts, I couldn't pay close attention to it until it began to display the error;

"Boot Device not found. Please install an operating system on your
hard disk. Hard disk (3F0)"

I have now removed the fan and cleaned the dirts and dusts and it works better. However, the problem persists - the PC is still unable to boot and keeps showing same error above.
I have removed the HDD and tried it as an external HDD and it's very well accessible via USB HDD casing. Yet, when I fix it back to the PC it still can't boot. I read somewhere that suggested my bootloader may have become corrupt and that I could try to repair it using a bootable USB flash drive with Windows 10.
The steps says I should boot from USB and start cmd using "shift f10" when I get to the language selection screen.
it says I should enter "dir c" to try to access the drive and suggested other commands to try to repair it.
However, when I try the "dir c" command, it says access denied and I can't seem to change permission not take control of the drive in order to successfully execute the suggested commands.
The steps are as follows

dir c:
bcdboot c:\Windows /s c:
diskpart
list disk
sel disk c..... and a number of other commands.

The problem is that I'm unable to get these commands to work because it says "Error: Access Denied" when I run them. I have also tried to take ownership of the drive here using the "takeown" command in order to be able to run the commands, but with no success.
Windows 10 and Ubuntu 24 installations are unable to start with this issue.

Based on your description of the problem, your storage device failed.  Once your storage device fails, there really isn't anything you can do other than reinstall the operating systems on a new disk and then extract your data from the original drive.

Thank you. But I'm still able to access the HDD via USB. This is why I suspect it may still be fine.
Additionally, if I access Windows command prompt via recovery/Windows installation interface, how can I take full control of drive c which keeps saying "Access Denied" when I type "dir c:" command, so I can run the boot repair commands and see if the installation can be repaired?
Thanks again.

Being able to read parts of the drive does not mean the entire drive is working. Being able to access the drive via USB means you have the chance to backup your data before the drive finishes dying. You have already attempted the methods for repairing the boot portions of the drive. Though, takeown probably destroyed the current Windows install irretrievably, as it would have reset permissions on the entire drive, breaking required Windows permissions.
